# memory allocation of character in c and java

Tags: java, c, string

How does memory space allocation affects the operations on string like length in (both) C and in Java ?
(This is in reference to the fact that C string variable packs 4 bytes per word where as a java string variable packs two half words per word)

Comment: What makes you think "memory space allocation" _does_ "affect operations on string"?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by `C string variable packs 4 bytes per word `

Comment: actually one word means 32 bits or 4 bytes

Comment: This is true in all 32-bit machines. Whether it is running C or Java and makes no difference AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact is that there ain't any C string variable in C , they are just arrays ;arrays of characters. One `char` in C occupies `1 byte`. The string literals are just stored as a array of characters and a terminating `\0` is appended at the end.

In the Java programming language, strings are objects.
A String contains the following:

1. **a char array**— thus a separate object— containing the actual characters;
2. **an integer offset** into the array at which the string starts;
   the length of the string;
3. **another int** for the cached calculation of the hash code.

This means even if the string contains no characters, it will require 4 bytes for the char array reference, plus 3*4=12 bytes for the three int fields, plus 8 bytes of object header. This gives 24 bytes (which is a multiple of 8 so no "padding" bytes are needed so far). Then, the (empty) char array will require a further 12 bytes (arrays have an extra 4 bytes to store their length), plus in this case 4 bytes of padding to bring the memory used by the char array object up to a multiple of 16. So in total, an empty string uses 40 bytes.

Calculating the memory usage by the string you will have to take into account the fact that a character in array is 2 bytes.

**JAVA->**`String.length()` is a constant time operation in the number of characters contained in the string because java string class stores the length as a field.

**C->** `strlen()` traverse the whole array until the `\0` to calculate the length of the string its runtime grows with the size of the string.

Answer (score 1):

A C string is a `nul` byte terminated sequence of bytes.

A Java String is an Object which has a length known and references an array of 16-bit `chars`

The memory allocation for a String is much higher, but it supports UTF-16 characters and an O(1) length operation. i.e. it can be faster in some cases.